# Refresh doesn't zero values, turns it into a list of values

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to do a bitfield with values from checkboxes in my form. However, whenever I refresh the page, or a submit validation fails, instead of zeroing the value, it turns it into a list.

```
var priceSum = 0;
$('.price:checked').each(function() {
    priceSum += parseInt(this.value);
});
```

This is inside `$('#form').submit(function() {})`

If there is no validation errors or refresh, I get the correct value. However if these events do happen, it turns the value into a list. For example, say validation fails twice before being successful, instead of getting 4, I would get 0, 0, 4

On further review, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with how I'm attaching this to the form
`var prices = $('<input>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "priceSum").val(priceSum);
$('#form').append($(prices));`

Would that just keep appending the value everytime? If it is, is there a way to drop a hidden field that already exists?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any way that could happen with this code. Can you show the whole code?

Comment: do you have an HTML ID priceSum?

Comment: no, it's just a variable I created to tally the bitfield values, declared within the `.submit(function() {})`, that's why I create the hidden input tag and append it to the form. At least I think that's what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't easily avoid to create the hidden input each time, you can first remove it if it exists:

```
$('#form [name=priceSum]').remove();
```

You can safely do that even if the input doesn't exist. Then it will just find zero elements, and the `remove` call will just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> Would that just keep appending the value everytime?

Yes. Only append the `priceSum` input if it doesn't exist.